# Is it preferable to create your own required desired function than to include whole library for some function

Tags: c++

Suppose i want to use some standard set function so is it good for me to use set.h or create my own files which contains declare and definition of function similar to set useful for my project . Will this in some way make my overall executable for library small or efficient or will save some memory as the complete libraries are not to be included .
I am little confused on this

Comment: Off-topic.  But in short, reinventing the wheel is a bad idea.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth what if i am using just 2 or 3 standard function from a library. Doesnt including the Whole library Whose use is limited should be a concern for me ?

Comment: To me, it depends on the library. For example, I wouldn't create dependency to Boost, just because of one or two functions (unless they are incredibly large and complicated, and error-prone for implementing).

Comment: Use `<set>`. It's a very non-trivial container, and the sheer number of errors you could potentially make trying to reinvent a lower-quality version of it simply isn't worth it. And as everything is template code, you aren't actually paying for any more than you're using.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks ... Anyways the quality could have been maintained using the standard algorithms and using them to write my function .. Regards :)

Comment: @Ritesh: It depends on what you mean by "set". The standard container is a balanced binary search tree, which gives you fast access, and that's a pretty complex piece of machinery right there. (Complex to author, that is, not costly in compiled code of course.) If you had something *else* in mind, then we're really comparing apples and pairs.

Comment: If you use one function from a huge template library, compiler will generate code only for instances of this one function you use (you might have a few instances, if you specialize this function with different types). If you use one function from a huge precompiled library and you link statically for standalone application, linker will only include this one function you use (plus, possible dependencies). In any case, you won't have in your executable any code that your program does not call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends:
If your question is about template library then the compiler generates code for only those template which you use so including the entire template code just increases your code size but not the generated binary size.

If you are talking of a non-standard non template library then the choice is a trade off between re-inventing the wheel or being okay with increased binary size. Choose whichever suits your project, If binary size is a concern reinvent the wheel for yourself, if not choose the library and be start building the vehicle since your wheels are already in place then.

Comment: you mean if i include stdlib.h  and alternately in second case i write my own function which is of same use as  atoi for my code instead of including stdlib.h . the binary generated will have same size in both the cases and there wont be any overhead of one over the second

Comment: @Ritesh: You misunderstand my answer.No it is not the same because the source code which you will write will be different(in all likelihood inefficient w.r.t performance,binary size etc) as compared to the one which standard library provides.